# Set REMOTE_ADDR to X-Forwarded-For in apache

Tags: apache, http, cgi

In a situation where Apache is sitting behind a reverse proxy (such as Squid), the cgi environment variable `REMOTE_ADDR` gets the address of the proxy rather than the client.

However, the proxy will set a header called `X-Forwarded-For` to contain the original IP address of the client so that Apache can see it.

The question is, how do we get Apache to replace `REMOTE_ADDR` with the value in the `X-Forwarded-For` header so that all of the web applications will transparently see the correct address?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use mod_rpaf for that. http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/

Comment: I'm +1ing this, but want to note that apparently rpaf doesn't take a network range. So if your provider is doing the balancing for you, you have to hope they never change their balancer IPs.

Also, ubuntu 12.04 doesn't correctly load the conf, you have to comment out <IfModule mod_rpaf.c> and the closing </IfModule> in the rpaf.conf or else it doesn't load that conf.

Comment: @DevNull: see the updated mod_rpaf, it supports CDIR ranges. https://github.com/gnif/mod_rpaf. This repository is the official one now as I have it over with permission from the original author.

Comment: @Geoffrey, glad you took over. The balancer I used at my hosting company said the source would be over a /24 network and with the older rpaf I had to put in 253 entries, one for each possible IP.

Comment: Apache 2.4 has a built-in [mod_remoteip](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_remoteip.html) that does just this, making mod_rpaf obsolete.

Answer (score 8):

Note that the X-Forwarded-For header may contain a **list** of IP addresses if the request has traversed more than one proxy.  In this case, you usually want the leftmost IP.  You can extract this with a SetEnvIf:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^(\d{1,3}+\.\d{1,3}+\.\d{1,3}+\.\d{1,3}+).*" XFFCLIENTIP=$1
```

Note the use of **$1** to set the XFFCLIENTIP environment variable to hold the contents of the first group in the regex (in the parentheses).

Then you can use the value of the environment variable to set headers (or use it in Apache log formats so that the logs contain the actual client IP).

Comment: I think your regular expression is incorrect: you want to grab the right-most IP address in the `X-Forwarded-For` header, not the left-most. Your expression should instead be `"^.*?(\d{1,3}+\.\d{1,3}+\.\d{1,3}+\.\d{1,3}+$"`.

Comment: I realize Wikipedia is the the definitive source, but it currently states the left-most IP is the client: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: So, who should I believe? :)

Comment: So the leftmost is indeed the client's IP, however, every IP-address afterwards should be checked and validated as so-called trusted proxies. As a pre-requirement you'll have to verify that each of these proxies also  check if their request makes sense. Something they should check for is clients spoofing, thus sending, the `X-Forwarded-By` header.

Answer (score 8):

Currently apache module mod_remoteip is the recommended way to do this; rpaf hasn't been reliably maintained, and can cause problems.

Comment: mod_remoteip does not send the real IP to the access logs. You have to modify the default LogFormat https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=806941

Comment: Yes, specifically you need to change %h to %a in the LogFormat line in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (or httpd.conf) for combined (or whichever log format you're using)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [mod_rpaf](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/) as mentioned before, it appears that [mod_extract_forwarded](http://www.openinfo.co.uk/apache/) will perform this function as well.

One advantage to `mod_extract_forwarded` is that it is available from [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) for RHEL/CentOS servers whereas `mod_rpaf` is not.

It appears that neither of these two modules allow you to whitelist an entire subnet of proxy servers, which is why the CloudFlare folks created their own plugin: [mod_cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/wiki/Log_Files) which, it should be noted, is *not* a general-purpose tool like the other two; it contains a hardcoded list of CloudFlare subnets.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can do this.

Just add a auto_prepend_file in your PHP.ini like `auto_prepend_file = "c:/prepend.php"`
and in this file add this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
```

You need the MOD_REMOTEIP in apache width `RemoteIPHeader X-Real-IP`.

Cheers,

Guiremach

Comment: I can't see that the OP mentioned anything about PHP. There are other server side technology besides PHP, in case you didn't know.

Comment: You are missing explode(','), end() and trim()

Answer (score 3):

Since **Apache 2.4** there is [**mod_remoteip**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_remoteip.html) built-in module that does this.

1. Enable `mod_remoteip`
   (e.g. `a2enmod remoteip`)
2. Create a list of trusted IP ranges (the IPs from which you accept the remote IP header). You can put them in a file like `conf/trusted-ranges.txt`
3. Add this line to the Apache config:

   ```
   RemoteIPTrustedProxyList conf/trusted-ranges.txt
   ```
4. Change your log file formats to use `%a` instead of `%h` for logging the client IP.

---

For **Cloudflare** you need to trust all their IP ranges **and** use a custom header `CF-Connecting-IP`:

```
RemoteIPHeader CF-Connecting-IP
```

You can get Cloudflare ranges like this:

```
curl https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4 > trusted-ranges.txt
curl https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6 >> trusted-ranges.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately,

at the time of this writing, none of the backports and forks at freshports.org, people.apache.org or gist.github.com worked. They were all based on an early alpha version of apache httpd 2.3 which was neither compatible with current versions of 2.2 nor 2.4.

So after hours of wasting time while trying to adjust the backports to create a real working one for httpd 2.2, I decided to move to httpd 2.4. Within httpd 2.4, mod_remoteip works smoothly, even if a load balancer has permanent keepalive connections which it uses to proxy requests from different actual client ip addresses to the backend. I'm not sure if the other modules can handle this situation (changing client ip addresses on each request within the same connection).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that this value can be spoofed. See http://blog.c22.cc/2011/04/22/surveymonkey-ip-spoofing/ for a real-life example with Cross-site Scripting consequences.

Comment: Which is why every mechanism to do this translation that I've seen (including the very useful rpaf module mentioned by maciekb) uses a REMOTE_HOST whitelist so that you know you're coming from a trusted proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the module **mod_extract_forwarded** and set **MEFaccept** parameter to all.