# How can I set REMOTE_ADDR in apache before php is invoked?

Tags: php, apache

I have a website set up with nginx acting as a reverse proxy to apache 2.2, which is running php.  From apache and php's perspective the IP address of all requests is the nginx server.  I'd like php to see the same remote IP that nginx sees.

Nginx sets a header X-Real-IP which contains the remote IP that nginx sees.  I tried doing something like this in the apache conf:

```
SetEnvIf ^X-Real-IP$ "(.+)" REMOTE_ADDR=$1
```

My hope was that I could set the REMOTE_ADDR environment variable and when php finally gets invoked, it would see the remote IP that nginx sees.  I think the php code is doing this:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Anyway, this isn't working. Can you not set REMOTE_ADDR in the apache config file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not sure whether `REMOTE_ADDR` can be changed that way...

Actually, you might need to install / enable another Apache module, like [`mod_rpaf`](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/) *(quoting)* :

> It changes the remote address of the
>   client visible to other Apache modules
>   when two conditions are satisfied.
>   
> First condition is that the remote
>   client is actually a proxy that is
>   defined in httpd.conf. 
> Secondly if
>   there is an incoming X-Forwarded-For
>   header and the proxy is in it's list
>   of known proxies it takes the last IP
>   from the incoming X-Forwarded-For
>   header and changes the remote address
>   of the client in the request
>   structure. 
> It also takes the
>   incoming X-Host header and updates the
>   virtualhost settings accordingly.
>   
> For Apache2 mod_proxy it takes the
>   X-Forwared-Host header and updates the
>   virtualhosts

Here's a blog-post about that : [Nginx proxy to Apache - access remote host IP address using mod_praf](http://www.kirkdesigns.co.uk/nginx-proxy-apache-access-remote-host-ip-address-using-modpraf)

Update: original link not working right now, but it is available also as a debian package: `apt-get install libapache2-mod-rpaf`

Comment: As a sidenote : I've had never heard of that module ; not sure if it's well supported / stable / maintained / ... ;; *nah, the name sounds funny ^^ not necessarily a bad thing*

Comment: I'm sure that given a pile of "Clever & Smart" comics, I could find the word used in a violent scene somewhere. To illustrate: http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/cleversmart.jpg (It's german, but it doesn't matter.)

Comment: @Pekka : In french, we sometimes *(well, some years ago, actually)* say "Et paaaffff le chien" -- "and paf the dog" ^^  ;;; @Russell : good to know ! I myself have an apache server behing an nginx used as reverse proxy, and I faced the same problem *(but "solved" it by patching my PHP script)*

Comment: `mod_rpaf` has been superseded by Apache's built-in [`mod_remoteip`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html).

Answer (score 11):

I have solved this using mod_remoteip for Apache. mod_remoteip is for Apache 2.5 but thanks to [this guy](http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?10,340545) you can use it on Apache 2.2.x as well.

Download mod_remoteip.c from https://gist.github.com/1042237 and compile it with

```
apxs -i -a -c mod_remoteip.c
```

This should create mod_remoteip.so copy in the modules directory. apxs will also add LoadModule directive in your httpd.conf for newly created module.

Open httpd.conf and check does LoadModule directive for mod_remoteip exists

```
LoadModule remoteip_module    modules/mod_remoteip.so
```

Add RemoteIPHeader directive in httpd.conf

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
```

This directive will instruct mod_remoteip to use X-Forwarded-For value from nginx as remote_addr. You can also use X-Real-IP instead:

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Real-IP
```

Restart the Apache. If you have set the proxy headers in nginx it will work like a charm and remote_addr in Apache will be correct

```
# nginx conf    
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Comment: But it looks like there is a problem if you use mod_rewrite. Rewritted URLs won't have correct remote_addr :(

Comment: mod_remoteip has a flaw and it doesn't work with mod_rewrite i.e. on rewritted URLs you will still get the 127.0.0.1. So at the end, the only right solution I found is mod_rpaf. Compile it and install it on similar way as I have described for mod_remoteip

Answer (score 3):

Apache (requires mod_headers module):

```
SetEnvIf X-Real-IP "^(\d{1,3}+\.\d{1,3}+\.\d{1,3}+\.\d{1,3}+).*" XFF_CLIENT_IP=$1
RequestHeader set REMOTE_ADDR %{XFF_CLIENT_IP}e
```

REF for SetEnvIf RegEx: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10346093

Works also but doesn't verify input as IP:

```
SetEnvIf X-Real-IP "^(.*)" XFF_CLIENT_IP=$1
RequestHeader set REMOTE_ADDR %{XFF_CLIENT_IP}e
```

In PHP:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

-or-

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

No non-core Apache modules required

Comment: Does not set REMOTE_ADDR, only HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR (apache 2.2).

Comment: Exelent solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may try this simple PHP module

https://github.com/yohgaki/realip

It simply rewrites $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] with X-Forwarded-For or X-Real-IP whatever header you like. You can accomplish this with many different method, but I just would like to do it as PHP module. So I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether REMOTE_ADDR can be manipulated - it could be that it can't - but you should be able to get hold of the X-Real-IP header within PHP through something like

$_SERVER["HTTP_X_Real_IP"]

or similar - check `phpinfo()` for the correct notation.

Also, Apache environment variables set in `.htaccess` should be visible in PHP.

Comment: One correction, it must be $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"], case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

mod_rpaf
(sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-rpaf)

resolved all issues and REMOTE_ADDRR now looks Ok!..

Answer (score 0):

Off the cuff.. but could you pass the header X-Real-IP as a variable to the php using some rewrite magic..? Can't htaccess do stuff with header information before it invokes PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use this actually: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_remoteip.html. Has quite a bit more features and is maintained by apache themselves.

Edit: I was referring to the mod_rpaf suggestion above.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache 2.4 you can define which field is used for that.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html

Answer (score 0):

I use the linux statement in Apache 2.4

```
sudo a2enmod remoteip
```