# REMOTE_ADDR IP from user instead of Nginx reverse proxy server

Tags: php, apache, nginx, proxy

I already read a lot of posts about this topic and tried several solutions but did not find a working slotion.

I have setup an Nginx reverse proxy in front of my Apache server. When my php application uses the **REMOTE_ADDR** function it gets the IP of the Nginx server instead off the user.

I'm using **Apache 2.4.10**, so module_remoteip.c should be installed. But it is not loaded.

Therefore I installed rpaf_module. It looks like this module is installed correctly, with phpinfo() mod_rpaf-2 is shown with the loaded modules. The I modified the **/etc/apache2/mods-available/rpaf.conf** file with the following content:

```
<IfModule rpaf_module>
    RPAFenable On
    RPAFsethostname On
    RPAFproxy_ips 172.19.0.5 # ip of Nginx server
    RPAFheader X-Forwarded-For
</IfModule>
```

My Nginx configuration look like this:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass 172.19.0.4;
}
```

Help is appreciated?

Answer (score 12):

The IP address of your visitor should be accessible using

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
```

instead of

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

If you want to replace the `REMOTE_ADDR` header, try this in your NGINX configuration: (And don't forget to reload/restart your NGINX-server)

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass 172.19.0.4;
}
```

Comment: That is correct, only I don't want modify my Symfony2 source code and keep that code standard.

Comment: After changing to your example and reseting Nginx & Apache, I still getting the Nginx IP address.

Comment: Try following the steps described at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8201447/3499277

Comment: proxy_set_header Host $http_host; get origin port

Answer (score 2):

To be able to get real-ip into the $remote_addr variable you need something like:

```
http {
...
  real_ip_header      proxy_protocol;
  real_ip_recursive   on;
  set_real_ip_from    0.0.0.0/0;
...
  server {
    ...
    listen 80   proxy_protocol;
    listen 443  ssl proxy_protocol;
    ...
  }
...
}
```

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/

Answer (score 1):

Add http config set_real_ip_from

```
http {
...
set_real_ip_from 172.19.0.5/16 # ip of Nginx server;
```