# How to read Client-IP with x-forward-for instead of LB IP on http requests in Apache config

Tags: apache, x-forwarded-for

I need for a RewriteCond syntax inside the httpd conf the real IP instead of the Proxy / Loabalancer IP. 
My use case is a maintenance page, that should be displayed to all users except some users from my exception list, defined by IP adresses listed in a seperate file.

I look already to [Set REMOTE_ADDR to X-Forwarded-For in apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247352/set-remote-addr-to-x-forwarded-for-in-apache) 
but I did not get the point I need.

I have configured the Logformat to

`LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i \"test\" %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined`

My Output is

`www.xxx.yyy.zzz "test" 10.0.0.215 - - [22/May/2019:11:09:20 +0200]`

but it could also be

`www.xxx.yyy.zzz, 10.0.0.12 "test" 10.0.0.215 - - [22/May/2019:11:09:19 +0200]`

So I need the first IP extracted in my use case.
What I have in my httpd.conf:

```
RewriteMap exceptions /appli/tecracer/apps/helios-fas/maintenance/exceptions.map

    # Allow Individual IP addresses past maintenance page
    RewriteCond ${exceptions:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} =OK
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Instead of REMOTE_ADDR I need here the real IP, the first entry of the X-Forward-For Header information.
How I can get this extracted and can I trust, that the first IP is everytime the Client IP?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the remoteip_module apache module ?

you need to include it ,configuration is simple:

```
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
RemoteIPHeader x-forwarded-for
```

my proxy is haproxy, in the backend section:

```
option  forwardfor
```

*The forwardfor option ensures the forwarded request includes the actual client IP address.*

then the remote_addr will be the client IP